# How to find Distinct and Max value from ArrayList in vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, arraylist

I need to get distinct and max value from arraylist in vb.net. I did this in c# and it works like
suppose arraylist has values (1,1,2,4,5,5,60)

***C#:-***

```
_objarr.ToArray().Distinct().Max();  Result: 60
```

this works fine in c# but when i convert into vb

***Vb:-***

```
_objarr.ToArray().Distinct().Max()
```

then i got error `'Distinct' is not a member of 'System.Array'`
So please tell me how i can overcome this error in vb.net.

Thanks

Comment: Sidenote: Don't use `ArrayList` use `List(Of T)` instead

Comment: yes i can use generic list as well.let me try for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add using to your code

```
System.Linq;
```

[`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is an extension method defined in System.Linq.Enumerable

In vb.net you need to create an instance of your array